# Is is possible to entry after strategy.exit immediately?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

#### I would like to achieve that after reaching the take profit, the strategy.exit closes the current position, and immediately opens a new one. Is this possible?

#### I have tried a couple of different methods, but doesn't work.

#### Do you have any suggestions how can I do it?

```
//@version=5 strategy('Test', overlay=true, initial_capital=10000, process_orders_on_close=true, calc_on_every_tick=true) 
backtime = input(title='Period', defval=1) 
overbought = input(title='RSI Overbought', defval=1) 
oversold = input(title='RSI Oversold', defval=1) 
takeProfit = input(title='Take Profit', defval=1) 
stopLoss = input(title='Stop Loss', defval=1) 
showDirection = input(title='Show Direction Trading In', defval=false)

var contract = "Test"

isOversold(k) => xyz

isOverbought(k) => xyz

plotshape(isOverbought(1) and isOverbought(0), style=shape.labeldown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.new(#ff0000, 0)) plotshape(isOversold(1) and isOversold(0), style=shape.labelup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.new(color.green, 0))

var inOrder2 = false 
var inOrder1 = false

if strategy.opentrades == 0 
inOrder1 := false 
inOrder2 := false

if isOverbought(1) and isOverbought(0) and not inOrder1 

inOrder1 := true 
inOrder2 := false

quantity = 1
takeProfitPrice = close + takeProfit
stopLossPrice = close - stopLoss

entryPriceToString = str.tostring(close)
quantityToString = str.tostring(quantity)
takeProfitPriceToString = str.tostring(takeProfitPrice)
stopLossPriceToString = str.tostring(stopLossPrice)

strategy.entry('buyOverBought', strategy.long)
strategy.exit('exit', 'buyOverBought', limit=takeProfitPrice, stop=stopLossPrice)

if isOversold(1) and isOversold(0) and not inOrder2 

inOrder2 := true 
inOrder1 := false

quantity = 1
takeProfitPrice = close - takeProfit
stopLossPrice = close + stopLoss

entryPriceToString = str.tostring(close)
quantityToString = str.tostring(quantity)
takeProfitPriceToString = str.tostring(takeProfitPrice)
stopLossPriceToString = str.tostring(stopLossPrice)

strategy.entry('sellOverSold', strategy.short)
strategy.exit('exit', 'sellOverSold', limit=takeProfitPrice, stop=stopLossPrice)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the value of `close_entries_rule` is ["FIFO" (First-In, First-Out)](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy)

Try changing it to `ANY`. But there are limitations
You can see the documentation [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Strategies.html?highlight=fifo#closing-a-market-position)